# Getting KeyError: 'project' when try to run apportable load command

Tags: compilation, load, apportable

I am trying to load my coming objective C project using apportable load command on terminal. But I am getting KeyError: 'project' in starting. Could anyone please suggest.
e.g. 
Building with TARGET_ARCH_ABI:armeabi ARM_NEON:False
Building to /Users/nimitja/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nimitja/.apportable/SDK/bin/apportable", line 745, in 
    run(env)

File "/Users/nimitja/.apportable/SDK/bin/apportable", line 709, in run
    results = actionsargs.action

File "/Users/nimitja/.apportable/SDK/bin/apportable", line 86, in LoadAction
    return env.LoadApp(site_init.BuildApplication(env, env['BUILD_TARGET']))

File "/Users/nimitja/.apportable/SDK/site_scons/site_init.py", line 359, in BuildApplication
    return build.App(env, app_sconscript)

File "/Users/nimitja/.apportable/SDK/site_scons/build/**init**.py", line 477, in App
    print "Updating configuration parameters... Building Xcode project " + target["project"]

KeyError: 'project'

Suggestion are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely an issue from installing Xcode 5. Its xcodebuild does sub-projects (even without our tools scanning things).

Do xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer to switch your Xcode version back.

Comment: I have both 4.6.3 and 5.0, also, I already ran the tweejump example and am now getting this message with a fresh single-view iOS app built from the Xcode template